# How to map a function to a pre-batched ('BatchDataset') tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am making data windows (input, output pairs of windows) from time series data. I have already converted my time series to a tf dataset, where each batch has the number of time steps equal to the total window sizes I need.

```
 def make_dataset(data=train_df[0]):
    ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data=data,
        targets=None,
        sequence_length=total_window_size,
        sequence_stride=1,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=32
    )

    return ds
```

Example of the shape returned:

```
for example in tensor.take(1):
  print(f'shape: {example.shape}')

shape: (32, 48, 18)
```

What I need to do now is split the time dimension into my input-output pairs, and I have a function to do this, however, when I try to map this function to my 'ds' in the above function I get the following error:

```
'BatchDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

I am hoping someone can help me understand where I am going wrong? I am pretty new to tensorflow... My code is below, in this example 'input slice' and 'label_slice' are 0 and 24 respectively. So my aim is to split my batches into input-output pairs of length 24 each.

```
def split_window(features):
  inputs = features[:, input_slice, :]
  labels = features[:, labels_slice, :]

  inputs.set_shape([None, input_width, None])
  labels.set_shape([None, label_width, None])

  return inputs, labels
```

```
 def make_dataset(data=train_df[0]):
    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
    ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data=data,
        targets=None,
        sequence_length=total_window_size,
        sequence_stride=1,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=32
    )

    ds = ds.map(split_window(ds))

    return ds
```

```
tensor = make_dataset()
tensor

'BatchDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score -1):

Your snippet of code looks similar to the tutorial of [Time Series](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) in Tensorflow. Based on that, I modified the main class `WindowGenerator()` (excluded the parts of train/val/test datasets and output-labels selection) to a simpler class suitable to your question.

```py
    class WindowGenerator():

      def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift):

       self.input_width = input_width
       self.label_width = label_width
       self.shift = shift

       self.total_window_size = input_width + shift
       self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
       self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size[self.input_slice]
       self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
       self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
       self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size [self.labels_slice]

      def split_window(self, features):
       inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
       labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
       inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
       labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

    return inputs, labels

      def make_dataset(self, data):
       data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
       ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
         data=data,
         targets=None,
         sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
         sequence_stride=1,
         shuffle=True,
         batch_size=batch_size,)
       ds = ds.map(self.split_window)
    
       return ds  


input_width=24
label_width=24
total_windth = input_width + label_width
batch_size = 32

window = WindowGenerator(input_width=input_width, label_width=label_width, shift=1)
dataset = window.make_dataset(train_df[0])
```

I would recommend, though, to use `Dataset.window()`. It is simpler and more intuitive.

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_df[0])
dataset = dataset.window(total_windth, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(batch_size))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-label_width], window[-input_width:]))
```